# How to deep copy a map and then clear the original?

Tags: dictionary, go

I'm trying to copy the contents of a map ( `amap` ) inside another one (`aSuperMap`) and then clear  `amap` so that it can take  new values on the next iteration/loop. 
  The issue is that you can't clear the map [without to clear its reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23058707/3257971) in the supermap as well.
 Here is some pseudo code.

```
for something := range fruits{
        aMap := make(map[string]aStruct)
        aSuperMap := make(map[string]map[string]aStruct)

        for x := range something{
            aMap[x] = aData
            aSuperMap[y] = aMap
            delete(aMap, x)
    }
//save aSuperMap
  saveASuperMap(something)

}
```

I've also tried some dynamic stuff but obviously it throws an error (cannot assign to nil)

```
aSuperMap[y][x] = aData
```

The question is how can I create an associative map ? In PHP I simply use  aSuperMap[y][x] = aData. It seems that golang doesn't have any obvious method. If I delete  `delete(aMap, x)` its reference from the super map is deleted as well. If I don't delete it the supermap ends up with duplicate data. Basically on each loop it gets `aMap` with the new value plus all the old values.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You are not copying the map, but the reference to the map. Your `delete` thus modifies the values in both your original map and the super map. To copy a map, you have to use a `for` loop like this:

```
for k,v := range originalMap {
  newMap[k] = v
}
```

Here's an example from the now-retired SO documentation:

```
// Create the original map
originalMap := make(map[string]int)
originalMap["one"] = 1
originalMap["two"] = 2

// Create the target map
targetMap := make(map[string]int)

// Copy from the original map to the target map
for key, value := range originalMap {
  targetMap[key] = value
}
```

> Excerpted from [Maps - Copy a Map](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006194258/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/go/732/maps/9834/copy-a-map#t=20171006194258443316). The original author was [JepZ](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908210640/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149404/jepz). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/9834). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 732 and example ID: 9834.

Comment: In case originalMap is map[ map[string]interface{}], whose elements have same JSON structure, then in subsequent iteration, the original values in newMap[0] is overwritten by key:value pairs of originalMap[1]. Also newMap[1] is created with key:value pairs of originalMap[1]. Any explanation for this behavior ? How can achieve the same ?

Comment: Watch out, v is just a copy, so if you are doing something like newMap[k] = &v it will not work (it will always return last value in the loop). Foolproof way would be  newMap[k] = &originalMap[k]

Comment: You might want to promote preallocating the map with `targetMap := make(map[string]int, len(originalMap))`

Answer (score 32):

I'd use recursion just in case so you can deep copy the `map` and avoid bad surprises in case you were to change a `map` element that is a `map` itself.

Here's an example in a **utils.go**:

```golang
package utils

func CopyMap(m map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    cp := make(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range m {
        vm, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
        if ok {
            cp[k] = CopyMap(vm)
        } else {
            cp[k] = v
        }
    }

    return cp
}
```

And its test file (i.e. **utils_test.go**):

```golang
package utils

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestCopyMap(t *testing.T) {
    m1 := map[string]interface{}{
        "a": "bbb",
        "b": map[string]interface{}{
            "c": 123,
        },
    }

    m2 := CopyMap(m1)

    m1["a"] = "zzz"
    delete(m1, "b")

    require.Equal(t, map[string]interface{}{"a": "zzz"}, m1)
    require.Equal(t, map[string]interface{}{
        "a": "bbb",
        "b": map[string]interface{}{
            "c": 123,
        },
    }, m2)
}
```

It should easy enough to adapt if you need the `map` key to be something else instead of a `string`.

Comment: Shouldn't this also include slice detection since slices can have the same effect?

Answer (score 6):

You can roundtrip it through `encoding/gob`:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/gob"
)

func copyMap(in, out interface{}) {
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(in)
   gob.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(out)
}

func main() {
   a := map[string]int{"month": 12, "day": 31}
   b := make(map[string]int)
   copyMap(a, &b)
}
```

This works with other packages too. Here is an example with `net/url`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/url"
)

func copyVal(v url.Values) url.Values {
   u := url.URL{
      RawQuery: v.Encode(),
   }
   return u.Query()
}

func main() {
   a := url.Values{
      "west": {"left"}, "east": {"right"},
   }
   b := copyVal(a)
   fmt.Println(b)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob
- https://golang.org/pkg/net/url

Comment: I like how clean this solution is, but I found that it's about 6-7x slower than a simple shallow copy. Maybe it would work better with a deep map?

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [seong's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057785/how-to-copy-a-map/53062590#comment35236077_23058707):

> Also see http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps. The important part is really the "reference to underlying data structure". This also applies to slices.

**However, none of the solutions here seem to offer a solution for a proper deep copy that also covers slices.**

I've slightly altered [Francesco Casula's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53062590/1720829) to accommodate for both maps and slices.

---

This should cover both copying your map itself, as well as copying any child maps or slices. Both of which are affected by the same "underlying data structure" issue. It also includes a utility function for performing the same type of Deep Copy on a slice directly.

Keep in mind that the slices in the resulting map will be of type `[]interface{}`, so when using them, you will need to use [type assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) to retrieve the value in the expected type.

### Example Usage

**Maps** (Will automatically deep-copy slices as well)

```golang
copy := CopyableMap(originalMap).DeepCopy()
```

**Slices** (Will automatically deep-copy maps as well)

```golang
copy := CopyableSlice(originalSlice).DeepCopy()
```

### Source

**`deepcopy.go`**

```golang
package utils

type CopyableMap   map[string]interface{}
type CopyableSlice []interface{}

// DeepCopy will create a deep copy of this map. The depth of this
// copy is all inclusive. Both maps and slices will be considered when
// making the copy.
func (m CopyableMap) DeepCopy() map[string]interface{} {
    result := map[string]interface{}{}

    for k,v := range m {
        // Handle maps
        mapvalue,isMap := v.(map[string]interface{})
        if isMap {
            result[k] = CopyableMap(mapvalue).DeepCopy()
            continue
        }

        // Handle slices
        slicevalue,isSlice := v.([]interface{})
        if isSlice {
            result[k] = CopyableSlice(slicevalue).DeepCopy()
            continue
        }

        result[k] = v
    }

    return result
}

// DeepCopy will create a deep copy of this slice. The depth of this
// copy is all inclusive. Both maps and slices will be considered when
// making the copy.
func (s CopyableSlice) DeepCopy() []interface{} {
    result := []interface{}{}

    for _,v := range s {
        // Handle maps
        mapvalue,isMap := v.(map[string]interface{})
        if isMap {
            result = append(result, CopyableMap(mapvalue).DeepCopy())
            continue
        }

        // Handle slices
        slicevalue,isSlice := v.([]interface{})
        if isSlice {
            result = append(result, CopyableSlice(slicevalue).DeepCopy())
            continue
        }

        result = append(result, v)
    }

    return result
}
```

**Test File (`deepcopy_tests.go`)**

```golang
package utils

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

func TestCopyMap(t *testing.T) {
    m1 := map[string]interface{}{
        "a": "bbb",
        "b": map[string]interface{}{
            "c": 123,
        },
        "c": []interface{} {
            "d", "e", map[string]interface{} {
                "f": "g",
            },
        },
    }

    m2 := CopyableMap(m1).DeepCopy()

    m1["a"] = "zzz"
    delete(m1, "b")
    m1["c"].([]interface{})[1] = "x"
    m1["c"].([]interface{})[2].(map[string]interface{})["f"] = "h"

    require.Equal(t, map[string]interface{}{
        "a": "zzz", 
        "c": []interface{} {
            "d", "x", map[string]interface{} {
                "f": "h",
            },
        },
    }, m1)
    require.Equal(t, map[string]interface{}{
        "a": "bbb",
        "b": map[string]interface{}{
            "c": 123,
        },
        "c": []interface{} {
            "d", "e", map[string]interface{} {
                "f": "g",
            },
        },
    }, m2)
}
```

Comment: This only woks when both map and the value stored in the map are `map[string]interface{}`, if `v` is `map[string]string`, in `mapvalue, isMap := v.(map[string]interface{})`, `isMap` will be `false`.

Comment: This will also fail where slices are not literally `[]interface{}`, e.g. `[]string{}`

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually copy each key/value pair to a new `map`. This is a loop that people have to reprogram any time they want a deep copy of a `map`.

You can automatically generate the function for this by installing `mapper` from the [`maps`](https://github.com/drgrib/maps) package using

```sh
go get -u github.com/drgrib/maps/cmd/mapper
```

and running

```golang
mapper -types string:aStruct
```

which will generate the file `map_float_astruct.go` containing not only a (deep) `Copy` for your map but also other "missing" `map` functions `ContainsKey`, `ContainsValue`, `GetKeys`, and `GetValues`:

```golang
func ContainsKeyStringAStruct(m map[string]aStruct, k string) bool {
    _, ok := m[k]
    return ok
}

func ContainsValueStringAStruct(m map[string]aStruct, v aStruct) bool {
    for _, mValue := range m {
        if mValue == v {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func GetKeysStringAStruct(m map[string]aStruct) []string {
    keys := []string{}

    for k, _ := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }

    return keys
}

func GetValuesStringAStruct(m map[string]aStruct) []aStruct {
    values := []aStruct{}

    for _, v := range m {
        values = append(values, v)
    }

    return values
}

func CopyStringAStruct(m map[string]aStruct) map[string]aStruct {
    copyMap := map[string]aStruct{}

    for k, v := range m {
        copyMap[k] = v
    }

    return copyMap
}
```

Full disclosure: I am the creator of this tool. I created it and its containing package because I found myself constantly rewriting these algorithms for the Go `map` for different type combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Individual element copy, it seems to work for me with just a simple example.

```
maps := map[string]int {
    "alice":12,
    "jimmy":15,
}

maps2 := make(map[string]int)
for k2,v2 := range maps {
    maps2[k2] = v2
}

maps2["miki"]=rand.Intn(100)

fmt.Println("maps: ",maps," vs. ","maps2: ",maps2)
```