# Concurrent read/write of a map var snapshot

Tags: go

I encounter a situation that I can not understand. In my code, I use functions have the need to read a map (but not write, only loop through a snapshot of existing datas in this map). There is my code :

```
type MyStruct struct {
   *sync.RWMutex
   MyMap map[int]MyDatas
}

var MapVar = MyStruct{ &sync.RWMutex{}, make(map[int]MyDatas) }

func MyFunc() {
   MapVar.Lock()
   MapSnapshot := MapVar.MyMap
   MapVar.Unlock()
   for _, a := range MapSnapshot { // Map concurrent write/read occur here
      //Some stuff
   }
}

main() {
   go MyFunc()
}
```

The function "MyFunc" is run in a go routine, only once, there is no multiple runs of this func. Many other functions are accessing to the same "MapVar" with the same method and it randomly produce a "map concurrent write/read". I hope someone will explain to me why my code is wrong.

Thank you for your time.

edit: To clarify, I am just asking why my range MapSnapshot produce a concurrent map write/read. I cant understand how this map can be concurrently used since I save the real global var (MapVar) in a local var (MapSnapshot) using a sync mutex.

edit: Solved. To copy the content of a map in a new variable without using the same reference (and so to avoid map concurrent read/write), I must loop through it and write each index and content to a new map with a for loop.

Thanks xpare and nilsocket.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve, could you explain more clearly.

Comment: This is 100% wrong. `MapSnapshot := MapVar.MyMap` does _not_ produce a copy which can be used concurrently to the "original".

Comment: You say that the pointer of MapVar.MyMap is the same as MapSnapshot ? Its a new var declaration, so it should be just a copy. Can you explain me why I'm wrong on this point ?

Comment: @Anarz map is a complex data structure, it's not an integer or string value, to copy with single assignment. It holds several other references to other things, and by the way `map[x]x` is itself a reference.read [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is no multiple runs of this func. Many other functions are accessing to the same "MapVar" with the same method and it randomly produce a "map concurrent write/read"

When you pass the value of `MapVar.MyMap` to `MapSnapshot`, the `Map concurrent write/read` will never be occur, because the operation is wrapped with mutex.

But on the loop, the error could happen since practically reading process is happening during loop. So better to wrap the loop with mutex as well.

```
MapVar.Lock() // lock begin

MapSnapshot := MapVar.MyMap
for _, a := range MapSnapshot {
   // Map concurrent write/read occur here
   // Some stuff
}

MapVar.Unlock() // lock end
```

---

#### UPDATE 1

Here is my response to your argument below:

> This for loop takes a lot of time, there is many stuff in this loop, so locking will slow down other routines

As per your statement `The function "MyFunc" is run in a go routine, only once, there is no multiple runs of this func`, then I think making the `MyFunc` to be executed as goroutine is not a good choice.

And to increase the performance, better to make the process inside the loop to be executed in a goroutine.

```
func MyFunc() {
    for _, a := range MapVar.MyMap {
        go func(a MyDatas) {
           // do stuff here
        }(a)
    }
}

main() {
    MyFunc() // remove the go keyword
}
```

---

#### UPDATE 2

If you really want to **copy** the `MapVar.MyMap` into another object, passing it to another variable will not solve that (`map` is different type compared to `int`, `float32` or other <s>primitive</s> type).

Please refer to this thread [How to copy a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057785/how-to-copy-a-map)

Comment: This for loop takes a lot of time, there is many stuff in this loop, so locking will slow down other routines. I am looking to make a copy of MapVar.MyMap which can be used as it and not linked by any way to the "original" MapVar

Comment: even you copied the `MapVar.MyMap` you'll end by performing loop on the copied object, so the `map concurrent write/read` will still happen.

Comment: change the `MyFunc()` execution to normal execution (not as goroutine), then inside the loop run each process as goroutine, so you'll get better performance. then you can remove the mutex.

Comment: So I guess I'm looking for the right way to copy the content of the object into a new var and not the object itself

Comment: I understand your approach and thanks for this. But I absolutely have to thread this func since it launch in another func which is a main part of a big software. So if I understand : to copy the content of a map, I MUST loop through it and write each value to the new map ? Just NewMap := OldMap will never work because it also copy the reference of the map because of the native data structure of a map which is not like any standard string or int value