# How can I find a data race in mutex-protected struct?

Tags: go

I have a struct containing a map that is accessed from different goroutines protected by mutex:

```
type Readings struct {
    sync.Mutex
    Timestamp time.Time
    values    map[meters.Measurement]float64
}
```

Still, it has a data race between `Add` (write) and `MarshalJSON` (read). The latter performs structure conversion:

```
func (r *Readings) Add(q QuerySnip) {
    r.Lock()
    defer r.Unlock()

    r.Timestamp = q.Timestamp
    if r.values == nil {
        r.values = make(map[meters.Measurement]float64)
    }

    r.values[q.Measurement] = q.Value
}

func (r *Readings) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    r.Lock()
    defer r.Unlock()

    res := map[string]interface{}{
        "Timestamp": r.Timestamp,
        "Unix":      r.Timestamp.Unix(),
    }

    if r.values == nil {
        return json.Marshal(res)
    }

    for m, v := range r.values {
        res[m.String()] = v
    }

    return json.Marshal(res)
}
```

This is the race:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000294900 by goroutine 11:
runtime.mapassign_fast64()
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/map_fast64.go:92 +0x0
github.com/volkszaehler/mbmd/server.(*Readings).Add()
    ...

Previous read at 0x00c000294900 by goroutine 25:
runtime.mapiterinit()
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/map.go:804 +0x0
github.com/volkszaehler/mbmd/server.(*Readings).MarshalJSON()
    /Users/andig/htdocs/mbmd/server/datagram.go:126 +0x304
github.com/volkszaehler/mbmd/server.(*data).MarshalJSON()
    ...
```

I don't understand what might by racey here and I'm not able to replicate the race behaviour moving the code into a standalone test case.

It there any advise for further diagnosis?

Comment: Are you sure the goroutines don't each have a pointer to a separate copy of the struct?

Comment: Is it possible that two `Readings` are sharing the same `values` map?

Comment: Both right. I had copied a readings, was calling Add on copy and MarshalJson on original. The values was shared, itself being not deep copied?

Comment: @andig: maps are reference values, they don't get automatically copied (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057785/how-to-copy-a-map)

Comment: If you also copied the sync.Mutex, note that a mutex cannot be copied after first use.  The `go vet` command flags this error.

Answer (score 0):

Both comments are right. I had copied a readings, was calling Add on copy and MarshalJson on original. The values was shared, itself being not deep copied.

Comment: This answer, in itself, is not very helpful because it just repeats a comment. I'd suggest to either (1) close the question or (2) significantly enhance the answer to show the code that caused the problem, so that others could learn from it in the future